# Проверка полей формы и wp_redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть форма на странице, после отправки данных из формы, создал хук для проверки данных:

```
add_action ('wp_loaded', 'my_custom_redirect');
function my_custom_redirect() {
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['review_direction'])){
    $errors = [];
    //проверка данных из формы
    $fields = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom_post',
        'post_title'   => $name, // заголовок поста
        'post_content' => $textarea, // контент,
        'post_status' => 'pending'
    );
    ...
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($fields)
    if(!count($errors)){
        wp_redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Здесь `wp_redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` нужен для отмены повторной отправки данных из формы при перезагрузке страницы.
Как теперь передать массив `$errors` в форму если есть ошибки при заполнении формы?
И правильное ли решение, приведённое выше, т.е. вынесение проверки формы в хук wp_loaded ?
Это получается на каждой странице будет срабатывать эта проверка?

**P.S.**
Если добавить в функцию `my_custom_redirect` этот код, остальные элементы массива $_POST из формы будут на странице, кроме `$_POST['errors']`

```
$_POST['errors'] = 'test';
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется удобнее как для пользователя, так и для Вас - отправлять форму с помощью ajax, проверять её на php и возвращать без перезагрузки страницы ответ. Ответ отправлять либо - "готово", или же массив содержащий ошибки, а там уже отображать ошибки как угодно. В сплывающем окне, над каждым полем формы, внизу формы или как Вам вздумается.

Добавим простую html форму с ID, который будим использовать в нашем JS файле при отправке формы.

**html**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="checkout-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name" required>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Ваш email" name="email">
    <input type="hidden" name="captcha"> <!-- Наше скрытое поле "каптча", если оно заполнено, то скрипт прекратит своё выполнение -->
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

**functions.php**

```
function payment_form() {
    if( isset($_POST) ){

        $errors = []; //Для удобства думаю при выводе(echo) скорее всего лучше перевести в json
        //проверка данных из формы

        //Проверка скрытого поля (невидимая каптча)
        if ( isset($_POST['captcha']) && !empty($_POST['captcha']) ) { //<input> name с captcha сменить на другой, например "input-name" и тут соответственно тоже
            array_push( $errors, 'captcha', 'false' );
            echo $errors;

            wp_die();
        }

        $fields = array(
            'post_type'     => 'custom_post',
            'post_title'    => sanitize_text_field( $name ), // убираем теги с заголовка записи
            'post_content'  => $textarea, // Нужно добавить функции с проверкой разрешенных html тегов и проверять контент
            'post_status'   => 'pending'
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($fields);

        if( $post_id ) { //Проверяем успешно ли добавлена наша запись
            if( count($errors) ){
                echo $errors;

                wp_die();
            } else {
                echo 'succes';
            }
        } else {
            array_push( $errors, 'post', 'false' );
            echo $errors;

            wp_die();
        }

    }
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_payment_form', 'payment_form' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_payment_form', 'payment_form' );
```

Теперь подключим обработчик формы, который расположим в папке с нашей темой->подпапка "**js**"

**function.php 2**

```
function payment_form() {
    //js
    wp_enqueue_script( 'form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/form.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'form', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php') ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'payment_form' );
```

Сам js файл, который будит отвечать за отправку данных формы на сервер.
**form.js**

```
var checkoutForm = document.getElementById("checkout-form");
checkoutForm && checkoutForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e){ //Проверяем, есть ли наша форма на странице
    e.preventDefault();
    this.querySelector("button").disabled = true; //отключим кнопку "Отправить" <button type="submit"></button>

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Если нужна поддержка старых IE, тут нужно доработать

    request.addEventListener('load', function(response) {

        //Тут прийдет либо succes или же массив наших ошибок
        console.log(response);

        this.querySelector("button").disabled = false; //Включим кнопку отправить
    });

    request.addEventListener('error', function() { //Произошла ошибка при попытуке отправки
        alert("An error has occurred! Refresh the page.");
    });

    request.open('POST', ajax_object.ajaxurl, true); //то что мы добавили в function.php 2
    request.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json');
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append('action', 'payment_form'); //экшен нашей формы в function.php
    request.send(formData);
});
```

Comment: после сохранения ajax-ом, и если перезагрузить страницу, то данные повторно также будут отправляться